Conver EFI qcow2 image with multiple disks to MBR/BIOS booting image
I'm trying to convert a custom rhel9.3 cloud install image that has been made to run in UEFI so I can run it on a BIOS system. Where I'm failing is to make my new image bootable. and the reason is that the image has 3 partitions:

EFI (500MB)

Linux (1.1GB) (grub folde, efi folde and vmlinuz files)

Linux LVM (50GB) -> this partition contains separate disks for to mount on each: /, /home, /var It shows as Primary but not as extended, is this right?


Step 1 Convert qcow2 -> raw
emu-img convert -f qcow2 -O raw customrhel.qcow2 customrhel.raw

Step 2 Mount image
sudo losetup -fP customrhel.raw

Step 3 Convert GPT to MBR with disk
sudo gdsik /dev/loop0

options: r , g , w
Step 4 fix partition table with fdisk (maybe here's my mistake)

I change partition 1 type to DOS, save and exit

Step 5 Install grub
sudo grub-install /dev/loop0p1 (partition 1)
unmount image, try to run it with virt-manager and it will not boot.
My doubt and probably where my mistake is: how I reconstruct the partition table in fdisk, and how do I install grub in order to make the image bootable again?
